# Windows 10 cloud storage provider (syncrootmanager) keeping handle to syncroot

Tags: registry, windows-10, explorer, cloud-storage

### Problem

I have a WinForms application that is registering a **cloud storage provider**. For reasons that do not matter for this question, the app sometimes attempts to move the folder that is the syncroot of the cloud storage provider with Directory.Move() (C#, .NET 4.5).

Under windows 10 (and only there), this leads to an **IOException** which is caused by an open handle from the **explorer.exe** to the **syncroot** of the cloud storage provider.

I tried to deregister the cloud storage provider beforehand, but I had to restart explorer.exe in order for that to work which is not really an option.

### Question

Is there a way (i.e. registering differently) to **prevent explorer.exe from keeping a handle to the syncroot**.

### Additional information

Attached are screenshots of the cloud storage provider in the registry. 
I had to pixelize some of the info due to NDAs.

Please also note that, besides the above, the cloud storage provider is working as expected.

---

syncrootprovider registration:
[image: syncrootprovider registration]

syncroot folder registration:
[image: syncroot folder registration]